# Running many docker instances on Google cloud with different command-line parameters

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Made computation docker which runs fine locally. Uploaded it to Gcloud and could run it. But what I really need is to run hundreds of instances with different argument each.

```
docker run -t dxyz arg0
docker run -t dxyz arg1
docker run -t dxyz arg2
...
```

What is the best way to do it? I tried Kubctl pods but looks like they supposed to be identical

Comment: They could all be identical if they called up a web service that distributed unique parameters to them.  They might also be programmed to dump data that way... The web service could then also provide a progress infrormation screen to a human manager...

Comment: @Paul yes, they could, but it means reprogramming them and then it will be somewhat different from local installations. Basically want single image running multiple options locally or on the cloud

Comment: @Paul but if there is NO WAY to do as I want it to be, then, well, web service might be an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty clunky due to the nesting and because it requires you to specify the replication controller's name and image twice, but you can technically use

`kubectl run dxyz0 --image=dxyz --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [ {"name:" "dxyz0", "image": "dxyz", "args": [ "arg0" ] } ] } } } }'
kubectl run dxyz1 --image=dxyz --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [ {"name:" "dxyz1", "image": "dxyz", "args": [ "arg1" ] } ] } } } }'
...`

Comment: aha! that's might be a answer I'm looking for... will check, thank you